# What touch event should i use as an alternative to on click for Iphones?

Tags: jquery, ios

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#register', function(){
      $('#registerM').slideDown('fast');
    });
```

If I'm using only `on('click')` works fine on android but it doesn't work on iphones, I tried using along with the click `on('click touchstart')` or `on('click touchend')` but that doesn't work either. Is there another touch event that i have to use or should this work and the problem is somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for `.touchUpInside` which means you clicked on the button and released it while your finger was still within the bounds of the button.

Here's where to find more info:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event/1618236-touchupinside

Here's an example of creating a button from scratch within a view controller:

```
func createButton(name: String, x:Int, y: Int) {
    let myButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
    myButton.frame = CGRect(x:x, y:y, width:150, height:40)
    myButton.setTitle(name, for: UIControlState.normal)
    myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(myButton)
}
```

If you want to know specifically on the touch but before the release then I would look at the `.touchDown` action.